# How do i call an Overload method from Constructor?

Tags: java

I trying to alternate way to call Overloaded method from Constructor, here's the brief code

```
import javax.swing.*;

Main() {
    JLabel label = new JLabel();
    new Map(label);
}

Main(JLabel label) {
    label = new JLabel("Label is here");
}
```

but it doesn't appear at all on my frame and it supposed to be working. What should i do?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] rather than snippets of pseudo-code.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
this(label);
```

instead of:

```
new Map(label);
```